# Center TH within table

Tags: html, css, html-table

Trying to centre a `<TH>` element within a table that is spanning two columns.  Whatever I try, the `<TD>` doesn't move.

```css
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  text-align: center;
}

.contacttable {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #FCF0F2;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}

th {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="contacttable">
  <tr colspan="2">
    <th id="tablehead">Contact Me</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>Email Address Here </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Telephone</td>
    <td>Telephone Number Here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like the 'Contact Me' TH to be centred over the two columns below?

[Screenshot of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcccO.png)

Comment: Typo: **cells** span columns inside a row, **rows** don't span anything.

Comment: If you have one `th` for every column in a table, then it should probably be a [caption](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `colspan="2"` as an attribute for that `th` (instead of `tr`) to make it span both columns:

```css
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  text-align: center;
}

.contacttable {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #FCF0F2;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}

th {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="contacttable">
  <tr>
    <th id="tablehead" colspan="2">Contact Me</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>Email Address Here </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Telephone</td>
    <td>Telephone Number Here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```